# Architectural decision and error handling for a RESTful API based system (using nginx + redis)

Tags: nginx, redis, restful-architecture

I am quite new in developing RESTful APIs on top of HTTP, so this is why I have some basic architectural questions. I'll leave authentication outside of the equation, for simplicity.

The RESTful APIs shall be handled by nginx (in reverse proxy configuration) and Redis. Some HTTP request/responses may use JSON in the HTTP Body.

What I am thinking to achieve, from a messaging perspective, is this:
1. (Client -> nginx) A RESTful API request is made to nginx over HTTP.
2. (nginx -> Redis) nginx will pass the API request to Redis and issue a "publish newRequest", after which nginx will wait for the response from Redis (using an nginx 3rd party Redis module). 
  2.1 I am not so sure yet how the above "wait for the response from Redis" will actually be implemented. I can however think of subscribing for an Redis event which will be published by my custom Redis "application" (see below), as soon as the request has been processed. Do you maybe know any better ways?
3. (Redis -> Redis "Application") The (above published) "newRequest" will wake-up its Redis subscriber, which is a Redis "application" (custom C++ code based on the Redis C++ client). 
4. (Redis "Application" -> Redis -> nginx -> Client) The Redis "application" will handle the request and after that will publish a response (for waking-up the Redis subscriber -from 2.1- and thus passing the "response" back to nginx and finally to the original caller)
  4.1 Now.. my Redis "application" may fail, so I would like to communicate such errors back to the original caller (using both HTTP response error codes + some descriptive JSON attached). But from my Redis "application" I cannot control the HTTP response error code (this is managed by nginx). So then I am wondering a bit.. how/where could then error handling be more cleanly implemented, such that my Redis "application" will drive the error handling, without having to update the nginx configuration for each new error I add in my Redis "application"?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All knowm (for me) nginx 3rd party Redis modules usually use basic request/response protocol, not long-live Pub/Sub. All of them use one of the main nginx feature - asynchronous subrequests to upstream servers. Asynchronous means that worker process doesn't block until response arrival, but continue processing others requests from clients and responses from upstream servers.

[Here](http://www.aosabook.org/en/nginx.html) is good overview of nginx features.

Your idea of "Redis Application" looks a bit weird for me and redundant.

With [redis2-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module) you have very limited possibilities to process your RESTful API by nginx conf files using Redis as storage. Most popular usage - just page caching.

But you may do something smart using EVAL command on Redis side. Not my preferred way.

I would recommend to use a perfect [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/) bundle.
With help of LuaNginxModule and LuaRestyRedis you may implement any smart logic within nginx and use Redis as storage. With LuaRestyRedis module you will be able to write very simple but still efficient code to handle subrequests to Redis in async way. You may even issue more then one subrequest to Redis in parallel or sequentially while processing one RESTFul request.

Also it has a LuaCjson module with JSON parsing and encoding support.

Pipeline will be much simpler:
client <-> nginx <-> Redis

Comment: In my initial post I basically intended to use Redis as a messaging queue (and this is not the main selling point of Redis). But given my short processing time for each request, I will not need a queue at all.